# IMPORTAR CSV CON PHP OPTIMIZACIÓN

Tags: php, csv

estoy tratando de hacer una herramienta con php para importar grandes bases de datos, metiendo varios value en un insert, pero no estoy logrando que me inserte los registros completo, siempre me faltan 1.000 o me faltan 500, o se adelanta el bucle y me inserta registros adelantados. La verdad que ya di con esto y he estado una semana buscandole la vuelta, quizas es el metodo que estoy utilizando no es eficiente. Yo hacia el import comun de linea por line agregando un insert, pero logicamente para una base de datos de 500.000 registros eso es muy lento. Quisiera saber sime pueden brindar un metodo, o algun error q tengo en mi codigo,desde ya muchas gracias.

```
     if (isset($_REQUEST['importar'])) {
    session_start();
    require('../../const.php');
    include('../../conectar/funct_conc.php');

    if (isset($_POST['importar'])) {
        //conexiones, conexiones everywhere
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $row=1;
        

        //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
 
         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {
            //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
            $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    // la cantidad del bloque *- prueba con un archivo de 50 lineas y prueba colocando 10 a ver si todo va como quieres. 
                $qtyToInsert =100;
$totals = 0;
// block lo uso para contar cuantos tengo en el bloque actual 
$block = 0;
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO express (id,cod_empresa,tipo,empresa,equipo,tarjeta,serie,idd,id_orden,id_actividad,identificacion,nombre_cliente,direccion,localidad,codigo_postal,provincia,fecha_creacion,telefono1,telefono2,fecha_de_envio,cartera,baja,id_fecha_recolector,remito_rend,remito_cv,fecha_rend_cv,id_operador_ren,id_motivo_ren,master_box,id_operador,fecha,id_motivo,tabla_oper,MULTIPLES,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,email_enviado,otros,remito_sub,fecha_remito_sub,fecha_asignado,id_recolector,operador,sub_asignado,ciclo,zona,fecha_premio,mes_base,R1,R2,R3,tipo_de_recupero,semanas,ano_semana,fecha_de_liquidacion,hist_pactados,latitude,longitude) VALUES "; 
 
            while (($entrie = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";")) !== FALSE)
            {
                

    // si no es la primera recuerda agregar una coma
    if($block != 0){
        $sqlInsert .=',';
    } 
    //agregas nueva linea
    $sqlInsert.="( '".$entrie[0]."','".$entrie[1]."', '".$entrie[2]."', '".$entrie[3]."', '".$entrie[4]."', '".$entrie[5]."', '".$entrie[6]."', '".$entrie[7]."', '".$entrie[8]."', '".$entrie[9]."', '".$entrie[10]."', '".$entrie[11]."', '".$entrie[12]."', '".$entrie[13]."', '".$entrie[14]."', '".$entrie[15]."', '".$entrie[16]."', '".$entrie[17]."', '".$entrie[18]."', '".$entrie[19]."', '".$entrie[20]."', '".$entrie[21]."', '".$entrie[22]."', '".$entrie[23]."', '".$entrie[24]."', '".$entrie[25]."', '".$entrie[26]."', '".$entrie[27]."', '".$entrie[28]."', '".$entrie[29]."', '".$entrie[30]."', '".$entrie[31]."', '".$entrie[32]."', '".$entrie[33]."', '".$entrie[34]."', '".$entrie[35]."', '".$entrie[36]."', '".$entrie[37]."', '".$entrie[38]."', '".$entrie[39]."', '".$entrie[40]."', '".$entrie[41]."', '".$entrie[42]."', '".$entrie[43]."', '".$entrie[44]."', '".$entrie[45]."', '".$entrie[46]."', '".$entrie[47]."', '".$entrie[48]."', '".$entrie[49]."', '".$entrie[50]."', '".$entrie[51]."', '".$entrie[52]."', '".$entrie[53]."', '".$entrie[54]."', '".$entrie[55]."', '".$entrie[56]."', '".$entrie[57]."', '".$entrie[58]."', '".$entrie[59]."') ";
    
    $block++;
    if($block>=$qtyToInsert){
        mysqli_query(conect01(),$sqlInsert);
        // reinicias block 
        $block = 0;
        // reinicias sentencia sql
        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO express (id,cod_empresa,tipo,empresa,equipo,tarjeta,serie,idd,id_orden,id_actividad,identificacion,nombre_cliente,direccion,localidad,codigo_postal,provincia,fecha_creacion,telefono1,telefono2,fecha_de_envio,cartera,baja,id_fecha_recolector,remito_rend,remito_cv,fecha_rend_cv,id_operador_ren,id_motivo_ren,master_box,id_operador,fecha,id_motivo,tabla_oper,MULTIPLES,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,email_enviado,otros,remito_sub,fecha_remito_sub,fecha_asignado,id_recolector,operador,sub_asignado,ciclo,zona,fecha_premio,mes_base,R1,R2,R3,tipo_de_recupero,semanas,ano_semana,fecha_de_liquidacion,hist_pactados,latitude,longitude) VALUES ";
    }
    // esto solo es el total de todos 
    $totals++;
    
}

// al salir si hay cosas pendientes ejecutas la ultima - no lo olvides
if($block > 0){
    mysqli_query(conect01(),$sqlInsert);
}



               
            }
            //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
            fclose($handle);
            $_SESSION['stat'] = "import";
            header("Location:../../vistas/data_new/index.php");
            exit();
            
         }
         else
         {
            //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
            //ver si esta separado por " ; "
            $_SESSION['stat'] = "noimport";
            header("Location:../../vistas/data_new/index.php");
            exit();
         }
    }
    exit();
}

  ?>
```

Comment: Si usas `mysql` lo que necesitas es [`Load Data`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). Dale una revisada. Saludos

Comment: Si, pero yo necesito hacerlo en un servidor de hosting, donde no siempre esta habilidata esa opcion.

Comment: Si esto es algo puntual deberías buscar una forma más ligera y segura de hacerlo, por ejemplo por consola (ssh). Si es algo que harás frecuentemente sí o sí tendrías que pensar en una forma de optimización extrema que no te bloquee el servidor. En ese último caso los caminos son múltiples y todo dependerá del contexto.

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga, a priori el problema es que no podes enviar una consulta muy larga a la función `mysqli_query`. **Seguramente algunas consultas estan fallando** y como no estas analizando el resultado de dicha acción no lo podes sabes (_¿si falla, cuando falla y por que falla?_). Toda la lógica del ver si `if($block>=$qtyToInsert){` no tiene sentido si la podes manejar con la función `fgetcsv` (_pidiendo chunks de 100_). Por último lo que te plantea _A. Cedano_ vas a tener que considerarlo ya que no veo que configures `set_time_limit`

Comment: A.Cedano. es buena tu respuesta, pues tengo que hacerlo una herramienta sencilla para que un operador sin conocimientos en php o mysql pueda importarla.

Comment: Por lo cual tiene que ser con una interface.

Comment: Usa load_data infile [mira este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915104/php-import-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-load-data-infile)

Comment: Usa load_data_infile
Mira este post
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915104/php-import-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-load-data-infile)

Comment: Hola rubtelo, recuerde que no esa funcion load data infile no esta siempre disponible para modo produccion en hosting. Ya revise este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915104/php-import-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-load-data-infile